# How to get OIDC provider (keycloak)configuration with the endpoint details?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, openid-connect, keycloak, istio

I'm trying to setup cloak with istio on k8s cluster and I'm following this [link](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice).
However, I'm new to the OIDC authentication. I have setup keycloak on k8s cluster and I'm trying to fill in the values in the template [here](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/blob/master/bookinfo-example/config/authservice-configmap-template-for-authn.yaml).

This requires values like the authorization_uri, token_uri, callback uri etc to be substituted.
Can anyone please let me know how and from where can these endpoint values be fetched and replaced? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keycloak offers standard OpenID Connect Discovery endpoint, e.g.:

```
https://<keycloak-domain.com>/auth/realms/<realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

You can get all required details from this endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

In case you came here searching for Spring Boot throwing NullPointerException when searching for well-known url.

There is a change in discovery url for Keycloak 18.0.0 (Quarkus). Now you don't need `/auth` in url

`https://<keycloak-domain.com>/realms/<realm>/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Below is sample spring boot keycloak configuration for openid-connect:

```
keycloak:
  realm: <your-realm-name>
  auth-server-url: https://<keycloak-domain.com>   
  resource: <your-client-id>
  public-client: true
  bearer-only: true

// for local development use 
// auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180
```